# Plumbing config - max trap arm to vent, top plate penetration, existing stack connection

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, kitchen-sink, p-trap

### Current Conditions

This is a slab foundation home in California and the kitchen is on the first floor. I am moving a kitchen sink to a new wall. It will be located beneath an existing window. To the left of the window, there is a stack + cleanout that serves the upstairs shower (shower only - other fixtures are on separate stack). To the right of the window is about 3ft of wall, the corner of the building and then 5ft of wall to the previous sink location

### Questions

**1. Is the trap distance to vent acceptable?**

- As best as I can tell, CPC allows 42" for 1½" pipe and the main thing to keep in mind is the trap weir must "see" the vent, so the slope will need to be fairly precise at ¼" per foot.
- While researching, I've come across other posts suggesting that the vent needs to reach 6"above flood as soon as possible before traveling horizontal.

**2. Are two side by side 2" holes in the top plate(s) acceptable?**

- Since I can't wet vent into a stack from 2nd story, my understanding is that I need to run a separate vent 42" above where the 2nd story fixture exists before tying in.
- I haven't taken drywall off and looked at the framing yet but I'm hoping there is enough room in the top plate between joists to run another pipe. But I'm wondering if this is allowed and if it is, how it is typically reinforced? With a Simpson strap like [this](https://www.strongtie.com/straightstraps_strapsandties/msta_strap/p/msta)? Do I need to add an additional 2x?

**3. Any suggestions on how I could configure this better?**

- I could possibly run the drain pipe to the left and the vent pipe to the right all the way to the previous kitchen vent pipe. Would likely have to go through cabinets or fur out the cabinets to avoid notching 8-10 studs.
- I can't run the vent pipe straight up to the second story on the right side because the floor/wall won't be accessible in that location (shower / tub).

[image: Diagram showing existing conditions in brown and gray, and proposed run in pink]

Comment: Yup, California throws you a bad curve ball with that "wet vent must be in the same story" language. I'd be inclined to put the vent connection in the stud bay and run it up towards "new vent line" connection, making the first sanitary tee into an elbow.